# How to generate a random normal distribution having mean 11.7 (in Python)

Tags: python, random, normal-distribution

I need to generate an array of 108 values following a normal distribution having mean= 11.7 and being the minimum value of the distribution 3.4, while the maximum value is 46.
I tried using `s = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 108)` but I don't know how to calculate sigma without having the single values.

Comment: A normal distribution has no minimum or maximum value. The problem is ill-posed.

Comment: If any, the minimum and maximum value should be symmetric around the mean.

Comment: @mkrieger1 no, it shouldn't

Answer (score 3):

You could use truncated normal distribution

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

r = truncnorm.rvs(a=3.4, b=46, loc=11.7, scale=1.0 size=108)
```

Sigma (scale) you have to know in advance from your domain problem